# TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "link" in the Next.js application

Tags: reactjs, testing, next.js, react-testing-library

In the Next.js application, I am getting the error

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "link"
```

while performing below assertion -

```
expect(screen.getAllByRole("link").length).toEqual(1);
```

for the anchor tag that is wrapped in Link Component of next.js

```
 <Link href={`/article/${Id}`} >
                    <a
                      title={Title}
                      onClick={() => {
                        ///
                      }}
                    >
                      {Title}
                    </a>
  </Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally we have the assumption that the default role for  is "link"
but that is not true.

- Anchor with href a[href] has the role of "link".
- Anchor tag without href Link has the  "generic" role.
  https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#svg

Here in Next.js application we are passing the href to Link and not to  so  is not getting the href directly at leaset it is not there when we try to see screen log using screen.debug()

Title

So the only solution I found was to provide the role manually in Next.js App

```
<Link href={`/article/${Id}`} >
                    <a
                      role="link"
                      title={Title}
                      onClick={() => {
                        ///
                      }}
                    >
                      {Title}
                    </a>
  </Link>
```